# Efficient algorithm to deal with big-data network files for computing n nearest nodes

Tags: c++, python, algorithm, r, bigdata

**Problem:**
I have two network files with me (say NET1 and NET2) - each has a set of nodes with unique ID for each node and geographic coordinates X and Y. Each node in NET2 is to have *n* connections to NET1 and the ID of *n* nodes will be determined by the minimum straight line distance. The output will have three fields IDs of node in NET1, NET2 and the distance between them. All the files are in tab delimited format.

**One way forward..**
One way to implement this is for each node in NET2, we loop through each node in NET1 and compute all NET1-NET2 distance combinations. Sort it by NET2 node id and by distance and write out the first four records for each node. But the problem is there are close to 2 million nodes on NET1, 2000 nodes in NET2 - that is 4 billion distances to be calculated and written in the first step of this algorithm... and the runtime is quite forbidding!

**Request:**
I was curious if any of you folks out there has faced similar issue. I would love to hear from y'all about any algorithms and data structures that can be used to speed the processing. I know that the scope of this question is very broad but I hope someone can point me the right way as I have very limited experience optimizing codes for data of this scale.

**Languages:**
I am trying in C++, Python and R.

Please pitch in with ideas! Help greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's the [Nearest neighbor search problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[kd-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) is one of the options. It allows you to find nearest neighbor (or a set of nearest neighbors) in reasonable time. Of course, you have to build the tree in the beginning and it takes some time. But generally, kd-tree is suitable, if you don't have to add/remove nodes in runtime, which seems to be your case. It also has better performance with lower dimension (in your case the dimension is 2).

Another possible data structure is [octree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree) ([quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) for 2D), it's simpler data structure (quite easy to implement), but kd-tree can be more efficient.

Comment: Do you know of any good implementation of this data structure in Python or C++?

Comment: In C++ Ive heard about this http://code.google.com/p/kdtree/ and http://libkdtree.alioth.debian.org , but haven't really used them, so don't know about the efficiency...